# spring boot response encoding not working

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, gzip, http-compression, content-encoding

I've configured my spring boot(2.5.5) application to enable  response encoding  by providing below properties in application.properties
I'm using the default embedded tomcat as a container

```
server.tomcat.compression=on
server.tomcat.compression.min-response-size=1
server.tomcat.compression.mime-types=application/json
```

my request headers contain `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
Still response is not being encoded.

I had digged a bit deep into the request flow by setting up breakpoints and found that there is a class
`org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol` having a method

```
 public boolean useCompression(Request request, Response response) {
        return compressionConfig.useCompression(request, response);
    }
```

What i find here is that the compression properties set by me in the config file is not propogated to the object compressionConfig. This still has the default values with no compression and minSize as 2048
if i try to tweak the compressionConfig object during the debug session and set the required values this works.
But how do i actually get it to work ? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spring boot 2.5.5 you should use properties like this:

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=300KB
```